# How to extract a portion of a datframe column and create another column with that extraction

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe like this:

```
id        Month  
 1     Month  01
 1     Month  05
 2     Month  12
...
```

And I wanted to extract the value from the `Month` column and add that extraction to a new column  `Month_no` and obtain this output:

```
id         Month     Month_no
 1     Month  01            1
 1     Month  05            5
 2     Month  12           12
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `Month` column has Month and number separated by a `whitespace`, you can use **[`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)**:

```
df['Month_no'] = df['Month'].str.split().str[1].astype(int)
```

Example:

```
In [1168]: df 
Out[1168]: 
   id     Month
0   1  Month 01
1   1  Month 05
2   2  Month 12

In [1169]: df['Month_no'] = df['Month'].str.split().str[1].astype(int)    

In [1170]: df                                     
Out[1170]: 
   id     Month  Month_no
0   1  Month 01         1
1   1  Month 05         5
2   2  Month 12        12
```

Comment: What does `str[1]` stand for?

Comment: `str[1]` stands for `index 1` after splitting.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively:

```
df['Month_no'] = df['Month'].str.strip('Month').astype(int)
```

Comment: @eduardo2111 can you confirm whether this works for you?